# Configure Firebase Analaytics + Google Tag Manager (GTM) per build variant

Tags: android, firebase, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

Before Firebase Analytics became available we use a multi flavour, multi build type Android Gradle project setup, and supply a different GTM container ID for each build variant, as follows:

```
TagManager.getInstance(context)
        .loadContainerPreferNonDefault(BuildConfig.GTM_CONTAINER_ID, -1);
TagManager.getInstance(context).getDataLayer().pushEvent(eventName, eventData);
```

where Gradle would inject different `GTM_CONTAINER_ID` per build variant.

How do we achieve the same with Firebase Analytics + GTM? According to [docs](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/), we need to download:

- a GTM container file from GTM dashboard [[1]](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/#add-gtm-to-project)
- a google-services.json file from Firebase console [[2]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/)

and then just start firing events with this:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).logEvent(eventName, bundle);
```

Where do we specify the GTM container ID to be used? Or is it auto derived by the file name we download from GTM dashboard and put under `assets/containers`? If so, how do we use different GTM configuration per build variant as we do with GTM legacy Android container?

Comment: @DevZer0 how come this is a vote spam?

Comment: @AnirudhSharma it is a joke between him and me, we work at the same company :) i am just waiting for him to ping me on slack :)

Comment: @DevZer0 Haha.Good one :)

Answer (score 8):

This is how we set up our Gradle multi-flavor project to use different GTM container for each build variant:

```
/
|_app/
  |_src/
    |_flavor1/
    | |_google-services.json # Google services config for debug
    | |_release/
    |   |_google-services.json # Google services config for flavor1
    |_flavor1Release/
    | |_assets/
    |   |_containers/
    |     |_GTM-ABCXY1.json # GTM container for flavor1
    |
    |_flavor2/
    | |_google-services.json # Google services config for debug
    | |_release/
    |   |_google-services.json # Google services config for flavor2
    |_flavor2Release/
    | |_assets/
    |   |_containers/
    |     |_GTM-ABCXY2.json # GTM container for flavor2
    |
    |_debug/
    | |_assets/
    |   |_containers/
    |     |_GTM-ABCXY3.json # GTM container for debug
    |
    |_main/
      |_res/
      |_java/
```

Assuming you have 2 flavors `flavor1` and `flavor2`, and want to have 3 GTM containers, 1 shared for debug build of both flavors, and 1 each for release build of each flavor.

GTM will connect to the FA dashboard of the project specified by your `google-services.json`. Multi-flavor multi-build type `google-services.json` support has been available since plugin version 2.1.0 [[1]](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54#issuecomment-209646611)

Answer (score 3):

The container ID is derived from the container file name, as you surmised. To use a per-build variant you can use gradle copy task to stage the correct container.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I think I'll go with resource merging for overriding assets: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging